# Array of objects with multiple match criteria does not match the filter

Tags: javascript

I want to return and output products that match the condition.

The returned results are not equal in the snippet.

What's wrong with this code?

I would also like to know how to allow empty condition values.

We have prepared items and conditions for snippets.

Please let me know the problem with the code below.

```js
const products = [
    {
        brand: {
            brandIdentifier: 'iXBQasXnRGqwerVR',
            name: 'DEVROCK',
        },
        season: '21-22 Autumn/Winter',
        modelNumber: 'DEVRLSM',
        productName: 'DEVROCK Long sleeve for men',
        color: 'Black',
        size: 'L',
        price: '160.00',
        quantity: 100,
    },
    {
        brand: {
            brandIdentifier: 'iXBQasXnRGqwerVR',
            name: 'DEVROCK',
        },
        season: '21 Spring/Summer',
        modelNumber: 'DEVRTSM',
        productName: 'DEVROCK T-Shirt for men',
        color: 'Red',
        size: 'L',
        price: '900.00',
        quantity: 100,
    },
    {
        brand: {
            brandIdentifier: 'iXBQasXnRGqwerVP',
            name: 'DEVPANK',
        },
        season: '21-22 Autumn/Winter',
        modelNumber: 'DEVPLSM',
        productName: 'DEVPANK Long sleeve for men',
        color: 'Red',
        size: 'L',
        price: '160.00',
        quantity: 100,
    },
    {
        brand: {
            brandIdentifier: 'iXBQasXnRGqwerVP',
            name: 'DEVPANK',
        },
        season: '21 Spring/Summer',
        modelNumber: 'DEVPTSM',
        productName: 'DEVPANK T-Shirt for men',
        color: 'Red',
        size: 'L',
        price: '900.00',
        quantity: 100,
    },
];

const extractionConditions = {
    brandIdentifier: 'iXBQasXnRGqwerVR',
    season: '21-22 Autumn/Winter',
};

const fuga = function(items, filters) {
    const result = items.filter(function(item) {
        for (const key in filters) {
            console.log(`${item.brand[key]}  !== ${filters.brandIdentifier}`)
            console.log(`${item.season}  !== ${filters.season}`)
            if (item.brand[key] !== filters.brand) {
                return false;
            }
            if (item.season !== filters.season) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    });
    return result
};


console.log(fuga(products, extractionConditions));
```

Comment: what's the expected output for the `extractionCondition` in your question?

Comment: I want to retrieve and output the data for products[0].

Comment: there's no `brandIdentifier` key in the products. `identifier` is nested inside `brand`.

Comment: You have edited the snippet. Still, the array is empty. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should adjust the keys of `products` to match the keys of `filters`:

```js
const products = [{
    brand: {
      brandIdentifier: 'iXBQasXnRGqwerVR',
      name: 'DEVROCK',
    },
    season: '21-22 Autumn/Winter',
    modelNumber: 'DEVRLSM',
    productName: 'DEVROCK Long sleeve for men',
    color: 'Black',
    size: 'L',
    price: '160.00',
    quantity: 100,
  },
  {
    brand: {
      brandIdentifier: 'iXBQasXnRGqwerVR',
      name: 'DEVROCK',
    },
    season: '21 Spring/Summer',
    modelNumber: 'DEVRTSM',
    productName: 'DEVROCK T-Shirt for men',
    color: 'Red',
    size: 'L',
    price: '900.00',
    quantity: 100,
  },
  {
    brand: {
      brandIdentifier: 'iXBQasXnRGqwerVP',
      name: 'DEVPANK',
    },
    season: '21-22 Autumn/Winter',
    modelNumber: 'DEVPLSM',
    productName: 'DEVPANK Long sleeve for men',
    color: 'Red',
    size: 'L',
    price: '160.00',
    quantity: 100,
  },
  {
    brand: {
      brandIdentifier: 'iXBQasXnRGqwerVP',
      name: 'DEVPANK',
    },
    season: '21 Spring/Summer',
    modelNumber: 'DEVPTSM',
    productName: 'DEVPANK T-Shirt for men',
    color: 'Red',
    size: 'L',
    price: '900.00',
    quantity: 100,
  },
];

const extractionConditions = {
  brandIdentifier: 'iXBQasXnRGqwerVR',
  season: '21-22 Autumn/Winter',
};

const fuga = function(items, filters) {
  const result = items.filter(function(item) {
    return (item.season === filters.season) && (item.brand.brandIdentifier === filters.brandIdentifier);
  });
  return result
};


console.log(fuga(products, extractionConditions));
```